# Adding two dictionaries together with items with same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have function that adds two dictionaries of the following item ('item_name': quantity of item). There was a bug and I fixed it but I don't understand how it works.

Here is my original code which doesn't work correctly.

```
inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 5, 'gold': 3000, 'dagger': 1}
loot = {'lock pick': 3, 'potion' : 1, 'lock pick': 4, 'potion' : 1, 'sword': 1}

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
  for item, quantity in addedItems.items():
    inventory.setdefault(item, 0)
    inventory[item] += quantity

addToInventory(inventory, loot)
```

When there are same items in loot, it doesn't add one of their quantities to the inventory.

Here is the code that works:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
  for item, quantity in addedItems.items():
    inventory.setdefault(item, quantity)
    inventory[item] += quantity

addToInventory(inventory, loot)
```

Why doesn't "invertory.setdefault(item, quantity)" double count the first item that it has to set the default value for?

Comment: Your `loot` dictionary has duplicate keys. So only one of them will be actually added to the dictionary. You should use a list of tuples or something similar.

Comment: Can you please give us an example of the outputs of both pieces of code?

Comment: Your second one does double the count. When I ran it, I got things like two swords. Your first code is correct, however you need to figure a way to get around the duplication of keys in `loot` as @thefourtheye suggests.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question. But FYI, `camelCase` is typically used for  class names. It can make it a little confusing when a function parameter is `camelCase`. Up to you, but i'd use `snake_case`

Comment: @thefourtheye Oh I see. This was an exercise from a book and in the original problem, loot is a list with duplicates, not a dictionary. I tried to make it work with the dictionary without realizing you can't have duplicate keys. Thanks!

Comment: @SCB You're right, it was bad testing on my part. In my earlier code, the duplicate items had the same quantity as well (I just copied and pasted the item) so when I ran the second code which does double count, I mistakenly thought it was working correctly.

Comment: @JamesSchinner Thanks for the tip! The book I'm using uses camelCase but it's good to know the general practice before I pick up a bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
loot = {'lock pick': 3, 'potion' : 1, 'lock pick': 4, 'potion' : 1, 'sword': 1}
```

isn't doing what you expect, the second instance of `lock pick` is overwriting the first. Since `loot` is a dictionary, it can only have one instance of each key. If you want to allow multiple instances of a type of loot, consider a list of tuples:

```
loot = [('lock pick', 3), ('potion', 1), ('lock pick', 4)]
```

And then your function would look almost the same:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for item, quantity in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(item, 0)
        inventory[item] += quantity
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `loot` dictionary has duplicate keys. So only one of them will be actually added to the dictionary. You should use a list of tuples or something similar.

```
inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 5, 'gold': 3000, 'dagger': 1}
loot = [('lock pick', 3), ('potion', 1), ('lock pick', 4), ('potion', 1),
        ('sword', 1)]


def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for item, quantity in addedItems:
        # This will get the existing value and add quantity to it. If the key
        # does not exist, `inventory.get` will use zero
        inventory[item] = inventory.get(item, 0) + quantity


addToInventory(inventory, loot)
print(inventory)
```

**Output**

```
{'dagger': 1,
 'gold': 3000,
 'lock pick': 7,
 'potion': 2,
 'rope': 1,
 'sword': 1,
 'torch': 5}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Is there an advantage or disadvantage of using "inventory[item] = inventory.get(item, 0) + quantity" over "setdefault(item, 0)"?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can only have one value assigned to each key in the dictionary. It looks like the behavior of Python is to use the latter value that you gave for each key.

```
>>> loot = {'lock pick': 3, 'potion' : 1, 'lock pick': 4, 'potion' : 1, 'sword': 1}
>>> print(loot)
{'lock pick': 4, 'potion': 1, 'sword': 1}
>>>
```